# HTTP Basic authentication user name

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I am using HTTP Basic authentication in a web application. Once the user enters the credentials into the browser login window, the application starts.

How can I retrieve the user name that the was entered in my javascript (ExtJS) based application?

Comment: Maybe in the httpd server vars... I mean, did you try something like print_r($_SERVER[]) after the authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the easiest way is to create a backend service (eg. a servlet in java) that will retrieve the userPrincipal name from the `HttpServletRequest` and return it in the JSON format. This way from the javascript page you can perform a normal AJAX call to query the service, and retrieve the principal (user name).